# Cap aborted error SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as user@abc.com: git exit status: 127

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

Hello I am getting cap error while deploying project into production server, can anyone guide me what is the exact error. Thanks in advance.!!

```
DEBUG [3b21fc00]    /usr/bin/env: git
DEBUG [3b21fc00]    : No such file or directory
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as user@abc.com: git exit status: 127
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: /usr/bin/env: git: No such file or directory

SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 127
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: /usr/bin/env: git: No such file or directory

Tasks: TOP => git:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as box-admin@s10.r5i.com: git exit status: 127
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: /usr/bin/env: git: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It seems like git is not installed or not within `PATH` on the remote host.

Comment: @slowjack2k thank you very much man you save me..!!!

Comment: @slowjack2k why didn't you add this as answer rather than a comment? This is a legitimate question.

Comment: @Donato the answer was in my point of view to short for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs  most commonly when git is not installed on your remote host or your `PATH` environment variable is not setup properly on the remote host.

Comment: Yes you are right actually I have setup a new server and I forgot to install git .. Thanks for your reply